# Absolute positioned div jumps outside containing div in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Having trouble with a couple of display issues in IE7.

Firstly, my large text headers display too far up in Internet Explorer (all pages)
Secondly, my descriptions on my Portfolio pages end up outside their containing divs.

Works great on FF/Chrome/Opera/Safari though!
You'll see what I mean: http://bit.ly/a3hUD4 (I've used bitly so my dumb questions don't show up when someone googles my website).

I've googled extensively. Not sure if problem number 2 is a overflow issue, or a absolute positioning bug in IE.

Here's the CSS for the centre div with the jumbo-text titles

```
.column1 {
padding: 103px 10px 10px 10px;
float: left;
width: 500px;
margin: 0;
}
```

And for the description div on the portfolio page

```
.porttxtbox {
text-align: right;
background-image: url(images/porttxtBG.png);
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
```

And it's container div

```
.portimgbox {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 480px;
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid #EAEAEA;
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Now that I notice, it's not just my jumbo page titles in column1, ALL of my columns are about 6 or 7 px higher than they are in webkit/gecko browsers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Heading Margins

<s>try with this</s>

<s>`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"  />`</s>

The `<p></p>` Tag with attribute line-height could not be rendered well in ie 7 or min version

Removing or replacing tag with a div could solve the problem, if problem persist you can use the gif spacer.. alway works :P

### Absolute Position

<s>ops.. I forgot
try to add in .porttxtbox left:0;</s>

Is better for specification typing the orizontal rule `left:0;` of a position:absolute, so there is no rendering fail with some browser, see ie7 or min version.

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. Body was already margin:0; padding:0; but why html?

Comment: That seems to have done it! Thanks Paper-bat. Any ideas for problem 1? 
Maybe I should mark this answered and start another thread.

Comment: because it reset margin of html tag that some version of ie apply to rendering

Comment: Great, I will remember that one.

Comment: but now seems going well, you have resolved the trouble of margin top??

Comment: try to emulate ie7 in ie8
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"  />

Comment: Same result in IE8's 'compatibility mode' unfortunately (the columns rise 6px). IE8 'normal mode' is all good though. I don't have IE6 on hand to test with.

Comment: seems that p don't like line-height: 150%; as spacer in img
I've done this <div class="hello"><img src="HelloThere2b.png" /></div>
also you can use a gif spacer instead <p><img class="myDamnHelloSpacer" src="spacer.gif" /></p> setting in css .myDamnHelloSpacer { height:6px; width:1px; } and should work :)

Comment: P.S.: I forgot.. ie 6 works the same as ie7.. but there is the problem of png transparecy :)

Comment: I removed the <p> tags around the img, and it turns out most browsers were adding the spacing that belonged to the text, except IE of course. Spot on! Cheers mate. You are a wonderful, wonderful beautiful person. >Internet Hug<